# DROP table using Room persistence library

Tags: android, android-room, drop-table

Is there any way to drop tables directly while using Room . I have tried the below code under DAO class
`@Query( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'tablename'" )
    void dropFavoriteShowEpisodeTable();`
But I am unable to build and error is

> UNKNOWN query type is not supported yet. You can use:DELETE, UPDATE, SELECT

I understand that during migration , I can directly drop tables using

```
database.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'tablename' );
```

But what if I want to drop a table at a later stage. How to achieve that ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: i'm not sure what you want to achieve with this. like you say dropping your table and updating your database structure can and should be done during migration. but dropping an table later is not really smart. if it need to be empty just delete all rows. but dropping an table in real-time create lot of nullable moments in your app.

Comment: check out @RawQuery or RoomDatabse.query()

Comment: read about https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery

Comment: @quantumapps You are right. Better cleaning all records than dropping.

Comment: @yeonseok.seo Uuhh , I dnt think that is of any help. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

No Room doesn't support Drop at all. You need to delete all the records by using

```
DELETE * FROM TABLENAME
```